# Implementing google places autocomplete API in iOS

Tags: google-maps, ios4, google-api, google-places-api

This is my first time that I am using Google API. I am having problem implementing Google places auto-complete API in my project. I am using the Google developers link to Google Places Autocomplete API as reference.

I am able to implement the [this](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/07/working-with-google-places-api.html) tutorial correctly, however, I am unable to implement [this](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) in iOS.

Can someone please direct me to some tutorial in this regard?
Basically I want to do the following:

When the user enters a text in UITextField,

- the URL string gets the text (which I have done successfully),
- a filtered array is populated
- the elements of the array are shown in a
  drop-down menu type thing just like in auto-completion link above.

Any help is in this regard will be highly appreciated. I am stuck on this problem for the past week.

Comment: You can try this one too, https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField

Comment: thanks this project is helpful

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete

It's an objective-c wrapper for the Google Places Autocomplete API.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 5):

And here's a Swift version :)

https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete

Answer (score 4):

And another alternative: https://github.com/TarasRoshko/TRAutocompleteView

Can be binded to any existing UITextField in single line of code. Supports customization, configurable. Should be good pick for UITextFields, handles resizing and orientation automatically. I've created it because all existing solutions do not provide simple drop down list for text field, but whole separate views, or even "placeholder text suggestion", sometimes even without a possibility to actually autocomplete.

Comment: Best answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a great way to understand how to implement the Google Places Autocomplete feature, I would recommend looking at the example below:

https://github.com/AdamBCo/GooglePlacesAutocomplete

Answer (score 0):

## Lightweight and Updated Solution!

- Maintains Cache
- Session cancellation over multiple request
- Multiple api supported

**Google Api Helper (Autocomplete)**

```
var input = GInput()
input.keyword = "San francisco"
GoogleApi.shared.callApi(input: input) { (response) in
    if let results = response.data as? [GApiResponse.Autocomplete], response.isValidFor(.autocomplete) {
        //Enjoy the Autocomplete Api
    } else { print(response.error ?? "ERROR") }
}
```

**Google Api Helper (Place Information)**

```
var input = GInput()
input.keyword = "chijucwgqk6mqtkrukvhclvqfie"
GoogleApi.shared.callApi(.placeInformation,input: input) { (response) in
    if let place =  response.data as? GApiResponse.PlaceInfo, response.isValidFor(.placeInformation) {
        //Enjoy the Place Api
    } else { print(response.error ?? "ERROR") }
}
```

**Google Api Helper (Many more)**

https://github.com/tryWabbit/Google-Api-Helper